# Manjaro, KDE - weird default font akruti2 in X11 windows

Tags: x11, manjaro

For some reason in my fresh installation of Manjaro the X11 always uses this weird looking font akruti2 as default (see for example `xfontsel` image below).

[image: xfontsel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [this forum](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue-is-in-english-but-uses-tamil-language-or-char-set-when-asking-to-compile-modules-on-linux/483976/2) I've found solution - to uninstall `ttf-indic-otf` package (and restart).

This fixes the problem. If you reinstall the package, the problem is back.

Honestly I gave up trying to find out how to properly configure the default font. I tried to google with some low effort queries like "how to set default X11 font" but the amount of useless results was too much.